# Is there a way to change a UITextField's cursor color other than .tintColor?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Basically, my goal is to have UISearchBarIcon.search be one color, and the cursor color be another. Since I have a dark and a light theme in my app I'm using alwaysTemplate for the UIImage for the search icon.

Found something about using this:
(textFieldInsideSearchBar?.value(forKey: "textInputTraits") as! String)["insertionPointColor"] = UIColor.red

But that doesn't seem to be valid as I get "Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'" in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

I think there have been no responses, because no-one understands fully.

Is this what you want?
[image: Search with colors]

I just set the UISearchBar with a tint colour of deep red - which is the cursor colour
It defaults to a light grey border and black text and a white background.
The light-grey colour can be changed with ***barTintColor***.

By setting barStyle to a UIBarStyle the choices are black, blackOpaque, blackTransparent and default.  They can act as a light(default) and dark(black) theme...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, the issue is the fact that I'm using a custom image for the search icon, so when using tintColor, it'll set the cursor and my custom image to red.

Comment: Ok now I understand, but I have no solution to separate their colours.  Have you seen a similar situation in another app?  It may not YET be possible.